Realm database is larger than json dataset
I've got 2 json files, one being 5.4MB and the other 3.1MB. These json files each contain one (big) string array. I'm adding all these strings in a single realm database with the following schema:
const Word = {
    name: "Word",
    properties: {
        _id: "objectId",
        content: "string",
        language: "string",
    }
}

Before calling realm.compact(), the database weighs 39.5MB, and 17.9MB after.
The following code is used to insert the data:
 Realm.open(config).then(realm => {
        realm.write(() => {
            const dataPath = __dirname + "/../data/";
            const files = fs.readdirSync(dataPath);

            for (let file of files) {
                const json = getJsonFileContent(dataPath + file);
                const language = file.substring(0, file.indexOf(".json"));

                for (let entry of json) {
                    realm.create("Word", {
                        _id: new Realm.BSON.ObjectId(),
                        content: entry,
                        language: language
                    })
                }
            }
        })
        realm.compact();

My question is: How come the database is actually bigger than the dataset itself? Should I use another database? Or should I simply keep the json files and parse them directly? Or maybe try and limit the amount of entries?
FYI, this database was meant to be used in a mobile app, and the realm JS version used here is 12.7.0.

Why would you expect the database to be smaller than the dataset? Realm doesn't currently compress strings, so a database file should be at least as large as the dataset it contains. There's additional storage needed for indexes and other metadata, which is probably not a lot if you only have 2 objects, but can become nontrivial for large amount of data. Finally, Realm will increase the file size at fixed increments, even if that means there'll be empty space in the file. This is done to avoid resizing every time a write transaction is made.

What @NikolaIrinchev said but also, what's the importance of the database size in this use case? It's roughly 10Mb vs 17Mb, right? Is that difference causing an issue in your code or are you just curious?

I was just testing things out indeed, and I did actually think that realm would compress strings. If it doesn't compress anything, everything makes sense.

It seems the original data is roughly 10Mb and the new data is about 17Mb.
There are a number of things that would account for that; indexes, metadata etc.
Also, the Realm object shown has an addtional propety
_id: "objectId",

and whenever that object is instantiated a new objectId is created which is 12 bytes along with the associated json data mapped to the object
realm.create("Word", {
   _id: new Realm.BSON.ObjectId(),

So the code is actually adding data to the original data so the files would naturally be larger.
For example; 1,000,000 objects * 12 bytes = 12M bytes of additional data (12 Mb)

As said in a comment above, I mistakenly thought that realm would compress strings. Since it does not, everything makes sense.
